# Заблокировать передачу IP пакетов используя IP Helper API

Tags: c#, c++, ip

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача - написать сетевой фильтр, который бы не пропускал пакеты на определенный IP-адрес.
В процесса серфинга по Инету нашла такой инструмент как IP Helper API. Но, к сожалению, самостоятельно не смогла разобраться, как можно заблокировать переход по IP-адресу.

Может, кто-нибудь уже делал что-то подобное и подскажет, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Может статья [Перехват сетевых пакетов используя C#](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/30450/) вам поможет.

Думаю что средствами SharpPcap это можно решить.

Comment: При попытке получить список устройств выскакивает ошибка:
Не удается загрузить DLL "wpcap": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

И я не уверена, что мне подойдет этот вариант. 
Как я поняла, с помощью этой библиотеки блокируются входящие пакеты, а мне надо не выпускать пакеты.

Comment: Так, вот с ошибкой я разобралась.
Но все равно я пока не вижу способа с помощью данного инструмента отлавливать исходящие пакеты, а не приходящие.